# about 'be worthy of ~ing', 'be worthy of being p·p'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

What's difference between

> His essays are worthy of reading.

and

> His essays are worthy of being read.

Is there anything ungrammatical in either sentence?

Comment: Most English speakers would probably say "His essays are worth reading."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning.

The second

> His essays are worthy of being read.

might sound more literary.